# How to concat two different ID's onto another table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine two values from same table into another table.

I have two tables:

```
Table: rawmaterials
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
product_code varchar(255) 
product_description varchar(255) 
allergens varchar(255)

Table: finished_product
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
product_code varchar(255) 
product_description varchar(255) 
products_containing varchar(255)
```

Here are some examples of data within the table Raw Materials:

Raw materials:

```
1   0207WIP Pearl Barley         Wheat
2   0202WIP Red Split Lentils     n/a 
3   0205WIP Yellow Split Lentils  n/a
```

I am trying to create a Mix inside the table `finished_product`.

As an example I will code the mix as `1010` name it as `Mix` and **containing is the part I am currently stuck at...**

I need to concat the product_code id's 1 and 2 from raw_materials into column products_containing table finished_products.

This is what I have tried so far, only to return the result but not update the table. As I want to figure out how it works:

```
select concat(product_code where id =1, product_code where id =2) from rawmaterials;
```

Can someone please guide me where I am going wrong with this query ?

Comment: More specific it's bad design because it's not normalized - what you want to do is create a table product for your `product` information and then another table `product_has_material` to connect them. Otherwise you can't hanlde the fact that some have 3 or 4 materials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this like:

```
select group_concat(product_code) from rawmaterials where id in (1,2);
```

But this is a poor design for your database; you won't be able to easily do things like find all finished products with a certain given allergen.

Try something like this instead:

```
create table allergen (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255);
);
create table allergen_rawmaterials (
    allergen_id int,
    rawmaterials_id int,
    primary key (allergen_id, rawmaterials_id),
    key (rawmaterials_id)
);
create table rawmaterials (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    product_code varchar(255),
    product_description varchar(255)
);
create table rawmaterials_finished_product (
    rawmaterials_id int,
    finished_product_id int,
    primary key (finished_product_id, rawmaterials_id),
    key (rawmaterials_id)
);
create table finished_product (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    product_code varchar(255),
    product_description varchar(255)
);
```

Then you create your finished product and then insert its raw materials separately:

```
insert into rawmaterials_finished_product (rawmaterials_id, finished_product_id) values
    (1, 1001),
    (2, 1001);
```